# How to show places when zooming in a specific area React Leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

On the page on the left side I have a map and on the right side I have a list of places. Markers for the map and a list of places comes to me from the database. I need to implement the following logic: when the user zooms in on the map, so that the list of places is filtered, and the places whose markers are not visible were not in the list. How can i do this?
Map.js:

```js
const Map = () => {
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "map-markers"));
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      setCoordinates(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <MapContainer
        center={center}
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        style={{ height: "100vh" }}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <MarkerClusterGroup>
      {coordinates.map((coord, index) => (
        <Marker
          key={index}
          eventHandlers={{
            click: () => {
              onSelect(index);
            },
          }}
          position={[
            parseFloat(coord.data.lat),
            parseFloat(coord.data.lon),
          ]}
          icon={defaultIcon}
        />
      ))}
    </MarkerClusterGroup>
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

List.js:

```js
const List = () => {
  const [houseTitles, setHouseTitle] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "map-markers"));
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      setHouseTitle(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "50%" }}>
      {houseTitles.map((title, index) => (
          <ListItem key={index} title={title.data.title} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I have seen is to use something called `react-leaflet-markercluster`. Leaflet has a library to cluster markers from a specific zoomed out location, then when you click or zoom, the markers tend to go independent.
What you do is basically wrap your markers around a cluster:

```
import MarkerClusterGroup from 'react-leaflet-markercluster';
 
<MarkerClusterGroup>
  <Marker position={[49.8397, 24.0297]} />
  <Marker position={[52.2297, 21.0122]} />
  <Marker position={[51.5074, -0.0901]} />
</MarkerClusterGroup>;
```

Here is the [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-markercluster)
Note: I've used this in production and it works without any problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you take a look at the updated question. I have implemented your solution in the project, but there is an error in the console

Comment: This error says you have a hook outside the component or inside the JSX, which is the wrong way of using hooks. 
Hooks start with `use` like `useEffect, useState, useContext, useEtc`. They can only be called here:

```

const Component = () => {
    // call your hook here 
  return (
     <h1>JSX here </h1>
   )
  }
}

```

If you call a hook above the component or inside the JSX, it gives that error. Another note, why don't you just use `onClick={()=> onSelect(index)}` in your Marker?